# Use Hashmap to Find Per Capita Data

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to find out how much crime takes place in a zip code per capita in Cleveland.

Each time a crime takes place it gets logged into my hash map as:

```
crimePopulationMap.put(zipCode, zipCodePopulation);
```

How do I count all the instances of all the zip codes and print them out with the per capita crime? So, I would have to add up all the times a zip code appears and then divide it by the population and I store the value as the population. Please help as I have not used hash maps before. I want to pass a generic hash map to this method too for getting these calculations.

Example for printing out to the console would be:

```
95103 0.0284
95123 0.0288
93143 0.0290
```

Comment: A zip code can not appear more than once in your HashMap, since it's the key of the map. It seems you don't really understand the principle of a Map. Read its javadoc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

You need *two* maps. One to track the population per postal code and another to track current count of crimes per postal code.

```
Map< PostalCode , Integer >  // Map of each postal code to a population number.
```

…and…

```
Map< PostalCode , Integer >  // Map of each postal code to a count of crimes.
```

On each report of a crime, increment the integer number in the second map.

To build your report of per capita crimes, call method to get a set of keys from each map, and combine them, in case the two maps do not share the same keys. Then loop that distinct list of postal zone values. For each zone, look up the population and look up the crime count. Then divide.

Answer (score 0):

reading the question I understand that the input is a stream of single crime events with related zip code.  Separately from that, you also have population number per zip code. You need to have two hash maps to hold this data.

1. zip code and respected population number map. this can be the map specified in the question.
2. Separate map for zip code and accumulating crime events. this map is defined as `Map<String, Integer>` (assuming zip is `String`) where key is zip code and value is a counter that gets incremented whenever the program is notified of a new crime event. [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method can be used to both initialize a new entry and increment subsequent calls:  `crimeCountMap.merge(zipCode, 1, (counter, one) -> counter + one);`
3. at any time, to produce the list of crime per capita for all zip codes, iterate over the keys of `crimeCountMap`, get the value for same key from `crimePopulationMap` and perform the division operation

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could achieve this stats:

```
// you need to preload this
Map<String,Integer> populationMap = new HashMap<>();
populationMap.put("95103", 100);
populationMap.put("95123", 200);
populationMap.put("93143", 300);

Map<String,Integer> crimeMap = new HashMap<>();
// update the counter with every event
crimeMap.merge("95103", 1, Integer::sum);
// update the counter with every event
crimeMap.merge("95103", 1, Integer::sum);
// update the counter with every event
crimeMap.merge("95123", 1, Integer::sum);

// to get the final stats
Map<String, Float> collect = populationMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(populationMapEntry -> {
            String zipCode = populationMapEntry.getKey();
            Integer populationInZipCode = populationMapEntry.getValue();
            Integer crimeInZipCode = crimeMap.getOrDefault(zipCode, 0);
            Float rate = crimeInZipCode.floatValue() / populationInZipCode.floatValue();
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Float>(zipCode, rate);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> entry.getKey(),
                entry -> entry.getValue()));
System.out.println(collect);
// {95123=0.005, 95103=0.02, 93143=0.0}
```

I used more variables than I should just to be more expressive.